# codeigniter : user profile page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, profile

Hello i have problem with the user profile page in codeigniter .
So here is my user controller :

```
  <?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    function users() {
        parent::user();
    }
    function index($id = null) {
    if($id == null) {
      redirect('/', 'refresh');      
    }
else {
    $data['title']  = 'User Page';
    $data['result'] = $this->users_model->get_user_info();
    $data['id'] = $id; 
    $data['main_content'] = "main/profile_view" ;
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
}
}
}
?>
```

And this is the function in the model :

```
public function get_user_info(){
        $this->db->where('id' , 'id');
        $q = $this->db->get('users');
        if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    }
```

And this is the routes file :

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/index/$1";

i get this error in localhost/cc/user/1 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_user_info() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cc\application\controllers\user.php on line 12
```

And i want to know how to display the user data in the view

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_user_info() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cc\application\controllers\user.php on line 12 & how to display the user info in the view

Comment: Your `users` model is never loaded.

Comment: the user_model is auto loaded

Comment: @MazenMezlini you should place that error in your question to explain that is the issue you are having.

Comment: @MazenMezlini that error is consistent with a model not being loaded. It is saying that `$this->users_model` is null. Is it perhaps `user_model`?

Comment: it's auto loaded and even if i load the model in __construct i got the same error

Comment: That may be true, but the error is telling you that there is nothing in the `users_model` property of your controller. So if it is loaded, it isn't loaded where you think it is loaded. A `var_dump(array_keys((array) $this));` will show you the properties the controller can access.

Comment: yeah my bad , i solved the first problem . thanks 
any way to display data from the model to the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller i think this line:

```
$data['result'] = $this->users_model->get_user_info();
```

should be:

```
$data['result'] = $this->users_model->get_user_info($id);
```

and in your model this:

```
public function get_user_info(){
        $this->db->where('id' , 'id');
```

should be this:

```
public function get_user_info($id){
        $this->db->where('id' , $id);
```

// ================= next question

*i tried it , but when i enter a non exist id after user/. , it displays the profile vue*

yeah i was going to wrap it in an IF but then got lazy -- here's one way
check if the result did not come back -- so after you check to see if $id is NULL -- if $data['result'] did not come back from the model then go to a method like showUserNotFound($id).

```
elseif ( ! $data['result'] = $this->users_model->get_user_info($id) ){

     $this->showUserNotFound($id); } 

else {    $data['title']  = 'User Page';
    $data['id'] = $id; 
    $data['main_content'] = "main/profile_view" ;
    $this->load->view('home',$data); }
```

Comment: i tried it , but when i enter a non exist id after user/. , it displays the profile vue

Comment: thank's work really good , i have another question  please , it's when you click on a user profile link , how to make it refer to the user profile page .

Comment: glad it helped! otherwise for user profile link question --- could you update your question and the code? i'm not sure which part of this you need help with.

Comment: it's really simple  , for example in the home i'll found that the user mazen has posted something , i want when i click on the username it refer automatically to : user/username